# NodeJS problem with utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql, query, json

I have a website with a chat system. This chat system has a table 'messages' and one of the columns is 'messagetext' set to utf8_general_ci(MySQL). In my website, I use php to query database. The results are ok.

In my app, i use NodeJS as backend but the results are like that: " Î±ÏƒÎ´Î±ÏƒÎ´  ". There are greek words stored in this column.

I have tried iconv-lite,iconv,utf8,decode Json.

My thought, in the website it's getting the value 'Î±ÏƒÎ´Î±ÏƒÎ' from column and decoding to utf8, that's how can I see the right results. BUT in app this is not happening, the results are the value instead of the actual word.

What can I do?

(from Comment)

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    sender int(11) NOT NULL, 
    reciever int(11) NOT NULL, 
    seen varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no', 
    datetime datetime NOT NULL, 
    messagetext text NOT NULL, 
    userseen varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no', 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=94 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Ref: [identical SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53055853/charset-utf8mb4-doesnt-work-in-nodejs-mysql-encoding-problem). Show some table structure/ mysql server versions. `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE '%character_set%'` from within your app and backend might show some useful results.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got this:  character_set_client
utf8mb4
character_set_connection
utf8mb4
character_set_database
utf8
character_set_filesystem
binary
character_set_results
utf8mb4
character_set_server
latin1
character_set_system
utf8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node.js needs something like this to start with:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({ ... , charset : 'utf8'});
```

Yeah, `ασδασδ` looks Greek to me.  What you have is "Mojibake".  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored for discussion of what causes Mojibake.

Do not use any form of encode/decode/conv -- it only compounds the problem. If that link does not help you, provide the extra details that it requests.

See also https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8

The form should mention utf-8:

```
<form method="post" action="/your/url/" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Analysis...

'Κ' (Greek Kappa) is the 2 bytes, hex 'CE9A', in utf8.
   'Îš' in latin1 is hex 'CE9A' (2 bytes)
   'Îš', if converted to utf8 is hex 'C38E C5A1'
   'ÃŽÅ¡' is that that looks like when interpreted as latin1.

Note: this last hex is what you show in your Comment.

So, you seem to have "double encoding".

```
SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT('ÃŽÅ¡' USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4) USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4);  --> 'Κ'
```

What is missing is where "latin1" is occurring in the flow of the data.

Comment: I set charset:utf8 in db connection and used var text = 'Î±ÏƒÎ´Î±ÏƒÎ´';
console.log(utf8.encode('Î±ÏƒÎ´Î±ÏƒÎ')); but I got: Ã�Â±Ã�Æ�Ã�Â´Ã�Â±Ã�Æ�Ã� . I have read this question about Mojibake  but i have done all these steps.

Comment: @BillyPap - Show us the entire string for the db connection.  Show us the table definition.  I assume you really want to work with `ασδασδ`, not after it has been Mojibaked.  `utf8.encode` only clouds the issue.

Comment: my db connection is -> var db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: config.host,
  user: config.user,
  password: config.password,
  database: config.base,
  charset : 'utf8'
}); and table messages is ->utf8mb4_unicode_ci / column messagetext -> utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: I just noticed something. When I write Καλησπέρα in a form and then send it to db, the words in column are -> ÎšÎ±Î»Î·ÏƒÏ€Î­ÏÎ± . I used a utf8 encoder/decoder and the actual utf8 encoding in the word Καλησπέρα is ÎÎ±Î»Î·ÏÏÎ­ÏÎ± . So the problem i think is encoding string to utf8. What do you think about it? How can i convert this  ÎšÎ±Î»Î·ÏƒÏ€Î­ÏÎ±  to this ÎÎ±Î»Î·ÏÏÎ­ÏÎ±    ? You can try this here: https://cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf_decode. Write Καλησπέρα, encode this and then decode. You will see that the result is different from the stored result in db ->  ÎšÎ±Î»Î·ÏƒÏ€Î­ÏÎ±.

Comment: Symbols like š, ƒ, € are boxes.

Comment: @BillyPap - Check out what I added about `<form>`.  Also, please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...`; I want to see if that is just Mojibake, or if it is "double encoding".  I can probably provide the conversion code, once we determine _which_ problem you have.

Comment: the return is  messagetext (col): ÎšÎ±Î»Î·ÏƒÏ€Î­ÏÎ±  and HEX(messagetext): C38EC5A1C38EC2B1C38EC2BBC38EC2B7C38FC692C38FE282AC...

Comment: i set form in the app  accept-charset="UTF-8" but same results -> messagetext (col): ÎšÎ±Î»Î·ÏƒÏ€Î­ÏÎ± and HEX(messagetext): C38EC5A1C38EC2B1C38EC2BBC38EC2B7C38FC692C38FE282AC...

Comment: Double encoding -- see further addition to my Answer.

Comment: Yes that’s it! What do you suggest to do? Can I use an sql order after I send data to db  (last_id)  and convert it?

Comment: The problem is that in my website the characters are ok with the format but not in my app. If I convert it using your method I can see the Greek letters in dB and in app but not in website. In website I get ????

Comment: @BillyPap - You said that NodeJS is involved.  Is there any other product?  The `createConnection` and the `<form>` and the `character%` look correct.  Still need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I am worried that _double_ encoding probably involves _two_ coding errors, yet we have not found any.  Those 'errors' probably involved a default "latin1".

Comment: messages
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `sender` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `reciever` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `seen` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
 `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `messagetext` text NOT NULL,
 `userseen` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=94 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: i recieved this from SHOW CREATE TABLE messages

Comment: @BillyPap - Ugh.  `????` -- is another problem discussed [_here_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) -- It usually means that the bytes were not utf8.  This implies that Node.js is not receiving UTF-8` stuff.  I am quite ignorant of Node.js; see if you can research it.  Perhaps you can catch the bad characters before it leaves node.js's hands and gets to MySQL?  Since latin1 cannot represent Greek letters, 'latin1' may not be involved.  Instead there may be cp1253 or something else.  Kappa hex is `CA`

Comment: Thank you for your time and your help Rick, I appreciate it! I tried $mysqli->set_charset('utf8'); and it's working!!